# ColdFusion 11 SOLR indexing logging conspicuous errors

Tags: solr, coldfusion

I am running a scheduled task to refresh my SOLR collection. The coldfusion-out.log file has quite a few of the following errors:

```
Jan 12, 2016 10:10:21 AM Warning [ajp-bio-8014-exec-5] - WARNING: Could not index D:\PDFs\9310.PDF in SOLR. Check the exception for more details: An error occurred during GETINFO operation in the cfpdf tag.
Jan 12, 2016 10:10:51 AM Warning [ajp-bio-8014-exec-5] - WARNING: Could not index D:\PDFs\9887.PDF in SOLR. Check the exception for more details: An error occurred during the EXTRACTTEXT operation in the cfpdf tag.
```

The task code to retrieve the file locations:

```
<cfsetting requesttimeout="3600" />

<cfquery name="getDocs" datasource="#APPLICATION.DataSource#">
    SELECT DISTINCT
        SKU,
        STATUS,
        'D:\PDFs\'
            CONCAT TRIM(DOCID)
            CONCAT '.PDF'   AS  document_file
    FROM    MYTABLE
</cfquery>

<cfindex
    query="getDocs"
    collection="prudocs3"
    action="refresh"
    type="file"
    key="document_file"
    custom1="SKU"
    custom2="STATUS" />
```

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: _Check the exception for more details_ Are you able to see any more details about the error?  Stack trace?

Comment: Make sure the said PDF documents aren't broken and can be accessed by CF. Start with a manual call to `<cfpdf action="getInfo" source="D:\PDFs\9310.PDF" name="docTest">`.

Comment: @Miguel-F I searched through the logs and could not find anything beyond what is recorded here.

Comment: @Alex good idea. I will try to debug this way with a few of the files.

Comment: I think it may be a permissions issue.... Investigating....

Comment: @Alex It looks like the PDFs throwing the "getdata" error are just non-existent files. No biggie. However, I still can't figure out what's causing the "extracttext" errors. When I run a <cfpdf action="extracttext" ... /> it just throws an error "Invalid File". Meanwhile, the file itself IS a valid PDF (I can open it in Adobe Reader).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While googling more about this, I came across this post from the wise Raymond Camden:

http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/07/11/Issue-with-CFINDEX/

Once I read this, I took a closer look at the PDFs being used, they indeed did not have the Extraction permission turned on. I have contacted the vendor about updating their PDFs, so that they can be properly indexed and included in search results.